# C++ which container to use for storing cache memory

Tags: c++, performance, stl

I'm currently writing a cache simulator, and I'm considering which container to use for this particular application.

I have to read memory from a file, which contains data in the following format:

`[instruction] [32 bit address] [amount of instructions since previous data memory access]`

example:

`s 0x1fffff78 1`

the instruction is always 's' or 'l', and the files range from 1 kB to 10 MB.

I'm considering using a Map, so I can pair the instruction with the address. But a Map is not very fast as far as I know with retrieval and insertion, which defeats the purpose of a cache.

A vector is my second choice, but this would make separating the three fields more difficult. I would use a vector of pairs if the files remained small, but this is not the case. Also since I would need to search by memory address this doesn't seem like the right choice.

Should I use a map, a vector, or are there faster/better alternatives?

Comment: not clear why it difficult if you use a vector. In general its rather meaningless to say vector is faster than map or the other way around. Do you need random access at given indices in constant time or do you need to find values given a key in constant time? This is what should drive the decision

Comment: Considering it's a cache, I need to find values by the address as key in constant time. I edited my question to reflect this

Comment: Can you have several identical address? Does order in the file important ?

Comment: There can be indentical addresses, yes. file order is not important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm considering using a Map, so I can pair the instruction with the address. But a Map is not very fast as far as I know with retrieval and insertion, which defeats the purpose of a cache.

`std::map` is generally way faster than the code you will write to handle it. This is especially true if you populate it with data from disk. **Do use `std::map`**. If it happens that performance is an issue, profile your code and come back with a question containing the result of your profiling.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` is also an alternative.

Comment: Good point in mentioning that disk access is more likely to be bottleneck. That alone actually makes it better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to program and use is probably just a `std::unordered_map` out of the box. If you really really need to tweak every bit of performance, a `std::vector` that you keep sorted and use for example `std::lower_bound` for lookup is probably faster, even for insertions in the middle. This is because of the linear contigous memory is just super fast. This could change in the future if for example the map classes is improved.

See for example this post for some benchmarks:
https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html